# Solving the Inhomogeneous Wave Equation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, potential

This question is based on a problem from JD Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, which asks for the solution of the inhomogeneous wave equation:  $$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2{A^{\nu}}}{\partial t^2}- \nabla^2{A^{\nu}} = \frac{-4\pi}{c}J^{\nu}.$$ I managed to find the solution using the Green's Function method, employing Fourier transforms: I obtained:

$$A^{\nu}=\frac{-1}{c} \int{d^3r'}\frac{J^{\nu}(\vec{r'},t_{r})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|},$$ where $t_{r}=t-\frac{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}{c}$ is the retarded time. However, the book seems to be asking for a solution for localized charge-current distribution, and the solution given there is:

$$A^{\nu}=\frac{1}{\pi c} \int{d^4\zeta}\frac{J^{\nu}(\zeta)}{R^{2}},$$ where $\zeta$ refer to the source coordinates $(\vec{r'}, t')$ and $R^{2}=|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|^{2} +c^{2}(t-t')^2$. Is it possible to convert the three-dimensional form to this four-dimensional form? My attempt at a solution was to re-write the three-dimensional expression as:

$$A^{\nu}=\frac{-1}{c} \int{d^4\zeta}\frac{J^{\nu}(\zeta)}{R^{2}} \frac{R^{2}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}| } {\delta(t'-t_{r})},$$ where the Dirac-Delta function has been used. However I don't understand how to transform this integral to the form mentioned in the text.

Comment: If you simply integrate the integral over $t'$, I think it should work.

Comment: Then it would become a three-dimensional integral: I wanted to know how to convert it to the four-dimensional form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... *the* solution of the inhomogeneous wave equation:  $$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2{A^{\nu}}}{\partial t^2}- \nabla^2{A^{\nu}} = \frac{-4\pi}{c}J^{\nu}.\tag{1}$$

To any particular solution, you can always add solutions to the homogeneous equation
$$\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2{A^{\nu}}}{\partial t^2}- \nabla^2{A^{\nu}} = 0.$$
and arrive at another solution. This is one thing to watch out for.

One general method you could try is to Fourier transform. It is probably instructive to see how this method sort of succeeds and sort of fails...

Anyways, Fourier transforming Eq. (1) gives
$$
\tilde A^\nu(\vec k, \omega) (-\omega^2/c^2 + |\vec k|^2) = -\frac{4\pi}{c}\tilde J^\nu(\vec k, \omega)\;,
$$
which can be rearranged and Fourier transformed back to find:
$$
A^\nu(\vec x, t)= {4\pi c}\int \frac{d^3k d\omega}{(2\pi)^4} 
e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec x-i\omega t}
 \frac{\tilde J^\nu(\vec k,\omega)}{\omega^2 - c^2|\vec k|^2}
$$
$$
=  \int d^3 x' dt' J^{\nu}(\vec x', t')\underbrace{{4\pi c}\int \frac{d^3k d\omega}{(2\pi)^4} 
e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec x-i\omega t}e^{-i\vec k\cdot \vec x'+i\omega t'}
 \frac{1}{\omega^2 - c^2|\vec k|^2}}_{this}\;.
$$

Now you just have to show that the thing marked "this" above is the same as the thing you are calling:
$$
\frac{1}{\pi c}\frac{1}{R^2}
$$

Comment: One minor clarification though: in this solution, where are we using the fact that we are adding solutions of the homogeneous wave equation?

Comment: If you look at the $\omega$ integral that you have to do you will see that there are poles on the real axis at $\pm c|\vec k|$. Therefore, you can't actually do the integral. You need to displace the poles off the real axis. There are two poles and two ways to displace them, so this gives you four different solutions. (See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Relativistic_propagators). These different solutions differ by solutions to the homogeneous equation.

Comment: (We're not adding or subtracting homogeneous solutions explicitly in this method; any addition/subtraction of homogeneous solutions is implicit in the pole-displacement prescription we choose. But since we end up finding different solutions to the inhomogeneous equation those different solutions must only differ by solutions to the homogeneous equation)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is under determined because you can always add free waves to your solution. This is why you get a different result from Jackson’s.

You implicitly chose the causal prescription, i.e. the current distribution only effects future fields. This is why you have the retardation effect.

Jackson’s solution is not causal. As you can see from the integration the current distribution can influence past fields. It is rather the Feynmann propagator. You can get it by solving the Poisson equation in 4D and then setting one coordinate to be imaginary so that it becomes time and recover the Minkowski metric (Wick rotation).

Both solutions differ by free wave solutions. In fact you can recover Jackson’s solution by taking the half sum of the causal and anti-causal solution (to get the latter change the sign so that the potential is not retarded but advanced). This is clearer to see from the various chosen contours to compute the solution from its temporal Fourier transform.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting! I know that it is generally against the trend in Jackson to use the Euclidean metric for Minkowski space, so I was wondering where that was coming from.